# IE not allowing onClick event on dynamically created DOM 'a' element

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, firefox, events

I'm having issues with internet Explorer. I have a link which duplicates a file upload element on a form. The code which duplicates also appends a hyperlink to the duplicated upload element which is supposed to remove the duplicated element a simple remove this link.

The issue is that this code runs fine in firefox but it doesn't run at all in IE. Forget how the code is written out - the onClick event which I attach to the element doesn't fire at all!

I'm creating my remove link element like this in the function:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.setAttribute('href', "javascript:void(0);");
a.setAttribute('class', 'delete');
a.setAttribute('onClick', 'removeThisElement(idOfParentContainer, this)');

container.appendChild(a);
```

This works fine in firefox but it doesn't fire at all in IE. I checked the dom using IE inspector and the link has rendered nicely however the class attached to it hasn't rendered or been applied and neither has the event fired even though it has physically been appended to the link on the html. For some reason the onClick event is not even firing no matter what code I put in it even if its an alert. Am I missing something here. :(

---

Great got part one of the issue solved by attaching events using AddEvent however why isn't the css rendering I mean the class attached to the element doesn't render at all for some weird reason :(

---

Good advice indeed - I'm rewriting my code to avoid the setAttribute function and instead porting all this DOM manipulation to jquery. Thanks for the helps guys

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<strike>Event handlers are not DOM attributes, the attribute exists in markup only - I'm not sure why FF oks this. I'll go research that now cause I want to know.</strike>

Update: seems to be mixed feelings about whether eventhandlers are DOM-valid attributes or not. Looks to me like this is MS's fault as they internally do not treat them as attributes, whilst the HTML spec indicates that they very much are. The direct consequences of this are that a number of things !IE would consider attributes cannot be set with setAttribute in IE including eventhandler bindings and importantly also **style, class and name**. apparently IE8 fixes this but I still haven't installed that so I can't check.

Meanwhile, for event binding use the [addEventListener/attachEvent](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html) pair instead, or (less preferably because it's a direct assignment) set a.onclick directly to your target method (or more likely a closure on your method).

To fix your styling not being correctly applied use `element.style = foo;` or (better) `element.className = bar`.

**Essentially the problem is setAttribute. Avoid using it.**

[For reference...](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/08/bug-242-setattribute-doesnt-always-work.html)

Comment: Whoa! So it means firefox has it wrong all this time! But how do I attach a function to which I wish to pass parameters - I can't seem to see any such example here though.

Comment: FF *may* be wrong, I'm still looking at that. You can effectively pass params using a closure: Pim illustrates what that might look like, can't be sure without seeing more of your code, but google "javascript closure" for more info.

Comment: I got it to work with out the parameters - but would still like to know how I would handle it should I require to pass parameters to the function attached to the event.

Also I can't understand why the css and styles don't render on IE as they should.

Comment: I think you'll have to provide us more code to work that out, but as I said creating a closure on the arguments to pass is the only way to get arguments into an event handler cleanly. Other possibilities include binding the argument data to the DOM element and retrieving it when handling the event based on the event.target/srcElement and of course there's going to be some wrapper for all of this in jquery.

Comment: The fact is that's pretty much the code that does it all - I just set the attributes using the set Attribute function. It renders such that its displayed but doesn't apply the style - instead however if I play dirty and hard code in the innerHTML it works fine :-S

Answer (score 3):

As annakata said you should use addEventListener/attachEvent. However if you wan't to set the onclick direct you can use:

```
  a.onclick = function() { removeThisElement(idOfParentContainer, this); };
```

Comment: fwiw, I didn't provide the code because the OP didn't either :) I have no idea what "this" or "idOfParentContainer" is, so I couldn't say if that closure would work.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this

```
var element = document.createElement("input");
element.class = "className";
element.style.display = "none";
element.style.position = "absolute";
element.id = "someid";
element.type = "file";
element.onchange = function(){
                   // do onchange functions here
                   }
// do the following that removes all browser dependecies
$(document.body).append(element);
$("#someid").click(); //click the button programatically using its id
$(element).remove(); // remove the element
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, for the cross-browser purposes, it's better to use Jquery.

```
$('#exampleCA').createAppend("a", { href: '#', style: "background-color: red;", onclick: 'alert (1);' }, "aaabbb");
```

This will create tag  with text aaabbb, href = "#", red background and alert event for click.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a reusable, X-browser solution, the following function works for IE, FF and Opera:

```
  function addEvent( obj, type, fn ) {
    if ( obj.attachEvent ) {
      obj['e'+type+fn] = fn;
      obj[type+fn] = function(){obj['e'+type+fn]( window.event );}
      obj.attachEvent( 'on'+type, obj[type+fn] );
    } else
      obj.addEventListener( type, fn, false );
  }
```