# Dynamic event-function binding isn't happening in vbscript / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, vbscript

Button 1 works fine, but when I try to insert button 2 dynamically the onclick event doesn't call its mapped function, any clue how it works? This is a simple example but later I need to capture events from complex object like trackbar's scroll event.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>a simple first page</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#form").append("<input id='button2' type='button' value='button 2'>");
    });
</script>
<script language="vbscript">
Sub Button1_OnClick()
        MsgBox "button 1"
End Sub

Sub Button2_OnClick()
        MsgBox "button 2"
End Sub
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form"><input id="button1" type="button"
    value="button 1"></form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding a new button to the DOM dynamically use the `live()` function of jquery:

```
$('[type=button]').live('click', function() { alert('Clicked button'+$(this).val(); } );
```

That'll add events to all current DOM elements and 'yet' to be created ones!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about VB script but this, you can attach a handler to any your button using jQuery live function or by assigning function on onclick event while creating your input and appending to form.

see example

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#form").append("<input id='button2' type='button' value='button 2'>");
    });

function button_2(){
alert('message 2')
}

// using jQuery live
$('#button2').live('click',button_2);

// other way attaching onclick value to input while creating it
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#form").append("<input onclick='button_2()' id='button2' type='button' value='button 2'>");
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

*How* does `Button1_Click` get called at all?  Is there some sort of implicit binding in IE, that I don't know about?  The way I'd do it is to add an event with `attachEvent()`.

[IE not allowing onClick event on dynamically created DOM 'a' element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771721/ie-not-allowing-onclick-event-on-dynamically-created-dom-a-element/771757#771757)

Comment: Yes, there is some implicit binding in IE even I am new to VBScript :)